# How to consult a file to swi-prolog in a faster way

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a prolog file (with the .pl extension), my prolog file is having at least >200000 rows (with file'size is ~20MB) at the current.
Whenever I want to use the file, I must load it to swi-prolog (I use 'consult' predicate), but with this way, it takes me much time to consult.. (>10 mintues now)

So, anyone knows another way to consult file with the minimum time, please help me.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should precompile your data: see [docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%284,%272.10.2.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/compilation.html%27%29%29).

*edit*: I'm sorry I suggested a wrong link above: the right one is [qcompile](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.3.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/consulting.html%27%29%29). Here a test with wordnet data:

```
?- load_relation(sk, N).
% /home/carlo/prolog/wordnet30/prolog/wn_sk compiled into wordnet 14,11 sec, 212,559 clauses
N = 3 .
```

after `qcompile('/home/carlo/prolog/wordnet30/prolog/wn_sk')`, that generates the .qlf:

```
?- load_relation(sk, N).
% /home/carlo/prolog/wordnet30/prolog/wn_sk loaded into wordnet 0,81 sec, 212,558 clauses
N = 3 .
```

qcompile perform a good speedup (almost 18 times faster), but requires some additional disk space.

*edit* on the full wordnet 3.0 relations (34.8 Mb) qcompile performs quite well: we pass from 69.8 sec to 3.1 sec. It requires 39.8 Mb additional disk space (for .qlf files).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try to learn about it

Comment: @hienvd_csuit: I've edited the answer with the proper example, sorry it took a lot to find the right tool...